# Print a string store into the stack - Tricky challenge

Tags: c++, stack

I found following C++ source code:

```
void victory()
{
  printf("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"); //random string
}

int main()
{
    if(0) victory();

    /* code here! */
}
```

**Your main objective is to print the random string(from function victory) on stdout**

How can It possible? How can I print the random string? It's a tricky traps, just for curiosity. Above all, I can't use pointers...

Rules: 
Max 12 chars. 
You can't use: "main", "victory", "asm", "%", "*", "_", "#", "/", "&". 
You have only one semicolon.

Comment: Looks like a code-golf question: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do you know the length of the string in `victory()`?

Comment: @NPE I suppose string length is length of "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx".

Comment: @leemes I didn't know codegolf section, apologize.

Comment: Any chance you can put any code into `victory`?

Comment: @chris nope, only where /* code here! */ :P

Comment: Considering there's no way to accomplish this without UB everywhere, it's not a constructive question. All answers will be situation-dependent hacks. And it sounds like you already have a solution in mind anyway; this is not a quiz site.

Comment: @tenfour I haven't any solutions... I am curios to know how can I do this... I'm thinking on it from some hours and I can't find solutions.

Comment: Consider (ab)using an unchecked buffer to do this.

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty clear that there is no way to solve this in any remotely standards-compliant way.

Since this is being framed as a "security" question, this suggest that it's OK to use compiler- and OS-specific hacks. With this in mind, the following works on my system using `gcc`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void victory()
{
    printf("SxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxE"); //random string
}

int main()
{
    if(0) victory();

    puts(""-25);
}
```

It relies on the fact that the `""` gets placed by the compiler immediately after the string literal that we're trying to recover. Here, `25` is the (known) length of the unknown string.

Of course, this has **UNDEFINED BEHAVIOUR** written all over it in huge neon letters. Handle with care.

Comment: :) I figured it would be some really unsafe hackish thing like this.